# nested variable assignment in bash

Tags: bash, variables, nested

How do I solve this in bash

I have a variable called `

```
DEV_IP=192.168.0.1
```

I have another variable called

```
ENV_NAME=DEV
```

How would I call `ENV_NAME` to get the IP Addess ?

like:

```
echo ${ENV_NAME}_IP
```

This is what I get when I run

```
echo ${"$ENV"_IP}
-bash: ${"$ENV"_IP}: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bash's metavariable syntax (*indirect expansion* as they call it) if you add a step:

```
KEY="${ENV_NAME}_IP"
echo ${!KEY}
```

With variables as you have, outputs:

```
192.168.0.1
```

From the [TLDP entry on Shell paramter and variable expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html):

> If the first character of "PARAMETER" is an exclamation point, Bash
>   uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of "PARAMETER" as
>   the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that
>   value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value
>   of "PARAMETER" itself. This is known as indirect expansion.

Comment: This is correct please look into indirection http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection

Comment: The TLDP entry is also almost a direct quote of the `bash` man page.